# replacing the contents of one file with another

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I want to replace the contents of each line of a file with each line of another file in Unix.

```
filetxt     keytxt
abc         pqr
def         uvw
```

Here `abc` should be replaced with `pqr` and `def` should be replaced with `uvw`.

Comment: you don't need `sed` for this: `cp keytxt filetxt` unless it's more complex than that in which case you should edit the question and add the details...

Comment: Do you mean replace the whole file with the other?

Answer (score -1):

You can use awk command but it will swap the text with each other. 
e.g.
paste first_file 2nd_file | awk '{print $2" " $1}'
$2 represents second line and $1 represents first

Comment: Um, do you have details on how to do that, or ... ?

Comment: your comment should be edited in to your answer to make the Answer more complete

Comment: I want that wherever abc is present in filetxt it should find it till the end of that file and then it should be replaced with the pqr which is present in keytxt and same with the other strings present in filetxt  .

Comment: can we use a loop for this.